# How could I go about turning this into a user managed area (if possible)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this Groupbox setup in a C# WPF:

[image: Groupbox Screenshot]

Lets say that the company ends up purchasing a new vehicle, how could that company add such vehicle to this window, without me having to add it to the designer like I have, and push out an update? If this is even possible. I feel like there is a better way of doing this.

The data the appears in these Comboboxes are names of drivers.

Comment: redesign to use a datagrid which would allow for additional vehicles to be added to the collection. the datagrid would have two columns. first column has vehicle name and second column combo box for names of drivers

Comment: So a Datagrid that isn't readonly, and has those controls inside of it? Drop the Groupbox I suppose too.

Comment: yes to dropping group box. it is not flexible to change. any time you have dynamic data that may change frequently you will need a more flexible control and data model.

Comment: I guess the biggest issue I would have is that when the data is dynamic, how am I supposed to make the second column a Combobox, since by default it will be a textbox row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base class for each such thing, let's say you name it `Thing`.

Use a [ViewModel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) (if you don't have it yet) with an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)<`Thing`>.

Then, in `XAML`, use an [ItemsControl](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) to define the [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) for each such thing and bind to the `ObservableCollection` in the `ViewModel`. (I suggest you use `WrapPanel` for the `ItemsPanel` property of the `ItemsControl`).

**That's it!** Whenever you add a new `Thing` to the `ObservableCollection` in the `ViewModel`, it will automatically add it to the UI!

Comment: I hear so much about MVVM, but have never seen it in use. Based off of reading about it, it sounds like it separates the UI from the program so that it can be designed to the user's needs. Am I correct?

Comment: It indeed separates UI from the logic, but not so much because of "designing to the users needs" but more for easier designing and coding. You dont have to worry about physically always setting UI elements, because everything is automatically taken from ViewModel using Bindings.

Comment: You could probably set this answer as the right one, so that the question can be closed.